# Compare Hour in R

Tags: r, time

Here is my sample dataset

```
id hour
1  15:10
2  12:10
3  22:10
4  06:30
```

I need to find out the earliest time and latest time. The class of the `hour` is factor. So I need to convert factor to an appropriate class, and compare the earlier and later time. I tried to format the `hour` using the code below, but it did not work out as expected

```
format(as.Date(date),"%H:%M")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `times` of `chron` package

```
#Data
xx
#  id  hour
#1  1 15:10
#2  2 12:10
#3  3 22:10
#4  4 06:30

library(chron)
xx$hour = times(paste0(as.character(xx$hour), ":00"))
xx
#  id     hour
#1  1 15:10:00
#2  2 12:10:00
#3  3 22:10:00
#4  4 06:30:00

#Min and Max
range(xx$hour)
#[1] 06:30:00 22:10:00
```

---

```
xx = structure(list(id = 1:4, hour = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("06:30", 
"12:10", "15:10", "22:10"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"hour"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is to find earliest (min) and latest (max) times, you can just convert the times to a character and use `min`, `max`: e.g.,

```
hour <- c("15:10", "12:10", "22:10", "06:30")
hour[which(hour == max(hour))]

> "22:10"
```